# Get rid of Relationship in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I have used this command to generate Database Context in MVC DotNET Core MVC using api.

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=localhost;Database=SongCollector;User ID=sa;Password=123" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Models
```

After that, my context models folder contain also relationship I don't want to have. Anyone can help with how to rip off these please.  When I sent a json to server it also contain other object with it. (lyric is the last att I want to sent)

Thank you.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: @aduguid thank you sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want the relations to be on the Song object, open that model file
and remove the properties you don't want.

After that create a new migration

```
dotnet ef migrations add RemovedSongRelations
```

Then you can update the database using:

```
dotnet ef database update
```

In case you only want the resulting object to not include the relation, just change your query.